# Checking if an image has an error?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I create an image:

```
var img = new Image();
    img.src = fileSrc;

    img.onload = function() {
            };
```

Is there a way to check if there is an error with the image?

I've tried:

```
img.error(function() { console.log("error loading image"); });
```

But I get the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

Comment: it should be `onerror`, also you have to use the `=` to assign the handler.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `Image onerror Event`

inline Ex.

#### HTML

```
<img src="example.png" onerror="imgErrorFunction(this)" />
```

#### JS

```
function imgErrorFunction(obj) {
    obj.src = '/404.png';
}
```

#### Edit:

Didn't realice that you use the image in a dinamic function...
Then error must be catched as **@King King** already suggest (same event).

```
var fileSrc = 'example.png';
var obj     = new Image();

obj.src     = fileSrc;
obj.onerror = function() {
    obj.src = '/404.png'; // must exist to avoid error loop
};
```